# In Redux, using middlewares to enhance store gives 'unexpected keys' error

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, middleware

I am getting this error:

> Unexpected keys "dispatch", "subscribe", "getState", "replaceReducer",
>   "liftedStore" found in preloadedState argument passed to createStore.
>   Expected to find one of the known reducer keys instead: "form".
>   Unexpected keys will be ignored.

My new redux store, with applied middleware is:

```
// redux extension
const composeEnhancer = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ || compose;
const enhancer = composeEnhancer(applyMiddleware(promiseMiddleware()));
const store = createStore(reducer, enhancer);
```

I followed the guidelines from here:
https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__` with `__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__`. The former is a complete enhancer that you can pass directly to `createStore` in case you're not using any middleware or enhancers. The latter is the composition function you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you very much, that did it.

Comment: This resolved it. Wish i could get better explanations.